# Scroll a Div when Scroll the page

Tags: jquery, css, html

This function jquery, scroll a div (with the css named "Search") when the user scroll the page..

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     $.each($('.Search'),function(){
         var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
         var finaldestination = windowpos+90; 
         $(this).stop().animate({'top':finaldestination},300);
     });
});
```

This function jquery doesn't work in Internet Explorer 9.
I tried to do a css that contain the attribute position:fixed but this doesn't work in Internet Explorer 9.
There is a solution that allows me to scroll a div when the user scrolls the page in Internet Explorer?
I apologize for the basic English

Comment: The only reason `position: fixed` doesn't work in IE9 is when the page is rendered in quirks mode, and that only happens when you have invalid HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine in IE. The CSS I used for search is

```
.search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zah8g/3/)

**Edit**

For a faster animation transition, clear the queue.

```
.stop(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use only css...

```
.search {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 90px;
}
```

See the [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zah8g/5/)

Greetings.